# Add a reply to comment button or @ autocompletion when using Chrome on Android

Tags: feature-request, comments, mobile-web, comment-replies, android

Currently there is no comment button or @ autocompletion when writing a comment in reply to another comment on Stack Exchange for mobile Chrome  on Android. It would be a good time saver to have this feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there plans to get the @ name completion working on the mobile website?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343178/are-there-plans-to-get-the-name-completion-working-on-the-mobile-website)