# Are there plans to get the @ name completion working on the mobile website?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mobile-web, autocomplete

I use Stack Exchange site through my phone (iPhone) way more frequently than I do through the desktop website. When I do that, I really wish that typing the @ symbol would offer the same auto-completion of names that it triggers on the desktop site.  Is anyone working on getting that feature working? If not, I'd like to ask that you prioritize it.

Comment: FYI [Add a reply to comment button or @ autocompletion when using Chrome on Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335767/add-a-reply-to-comment-button-or-autocompletion-when-using-chrome-on-android)

Comment: For what it's worth, this does work on the mobile app.

Comment: @Alex Only sort of. On Android, there is no autocompletion on typing, but you can tap an existing comment and tap the "reply" button to fill the username in.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I VTC'd your question as dupe of this, as this has an answer and status.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The question asks about iPhone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There will not ever be plans to implement this on the mobile theme.

We are actively working on the responsive design that works on both desktop and mobile, based on screen size. Once that is finished and perfected, mobile web will be slated for complete removal. While we still fix vital bugs for mobile web, you shouldn't expect any new features to be built for it.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that eventually the phone will have this feature because it'll be the same as the desktop site? To me, as a user, that's the same as fixing the mobile theme. So I'm happy with that. Any timeline for the rollout?

Comment: @SRM You can already use the responsive design by clicking "full site" at the bottom and making sure responsiveness is enabled. It's been available for some time.

Comment: Wow. Well, that "full site" link is definitely not well advertised! That works great! You should tell more people about that. Maybe a featured post on the various forums? (PS: You shouldn't mark "status-declined"... you should mark "status-done"!!! This completely filled my request!)

Comment: @SRM Strictly speaking in terms of the mobile site, this request is declined for it.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Yeah, but for the mobile user, it's fixed. I don't care how the tech is implemented on the back end ... I just want to be able to get name autocomplete on my phone... and that now works! :-)

Comment: That's true. However, as your question is still asking about the mobile site, the tagging is correct.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog What did I do to indicate that I was asking for the mobile theme specifically and not the website on the mobile device? How should I have differentiated?

Comment: @SRM I would have suggested removing the [tag:mobile-web] tag and writing "on mobile devices" instead of "on the mobile website" in the title.

Comment: @TannerSwett That would require me to know the difference. I just know that I accessed Stack Exchange through my phone. :-)

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the update. :) We've had both the responsive design and the mobile site for so long, I'd been wondering why we still had the mobile site. Turns out retiring it is still a WIP.