# Different syntax for uploaded image between full and mobile web

Tags: support, mobile-web, uploader

I just noticed that if I upload image via full web editor it looks like the following in code:

> [image: full web]

I.e. description with a link to the separate link list at the end of message body. But if I use mobile web the result is different:

> [image: mobile web]

Here’s inplace syntax is used.

Is it intentional, e.g. shorter form for a mobile client with reduced screen size, or just another developer point of view how the resulting code should be displayed in the message body?

On the other hand full web version link more narrow, i.e. better to use in portrait mode on the phone.

Comment: Mobile web is dead. It's no longer developed, they're not fixing its bugs, and won't add new features to it. So when the full site theme get new stuff, it won't be applied in the mobile web. That's just one case of many, and over time it will just get worse. (The plan is to replace it with responsive design, but the responsive design is still very very far from being done, 6-8 years is a very optimistic ETA.)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard is there an obituary for mobile web from SO employee?

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/152859). Well, turns out they'll still fix "vital bugs", but minor things like the one here won't be done. :/

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard BTW current question is marked [support], not a [bug]