# No title for badge related pages in mobile version

Tags: bug, badges, mobile-web, window-title

There is no title for badge related pages in mobile version. For instance:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic

- Full site

> [image: full site]

- Mobile site

> [image: mobile site]

I.e. html `title` tag is not filled for that page.

Comment: Mobile web is in the same state as the apps: dead, without active development. They won't fix any non-critical bugs. (i.e. I'm afraid you're wasting your time here.)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard wasting the time is my the best hobbi.

Comment: This is no issue on the responsive design. Status-no-longer-maintained?

Comment: @Luuklag [`[status-not-a-vital-bug]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/339911) maybe

Comment: @αλεχολυτ well, it's your time. ;)

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard according to post revision your time too :)